How to set the background color of the app in SwiftUI?
I want to set the background color for the entire app using SwiftUI.
What is the idiomatic way to do this?
I know there is an option to set a background color using a ZStack approach:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack { // 1
      Color.powder950.ignoresSafeArea() // 2
      
      Text("Hello, world!")
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  ContentView()
}

But it seems repetitive to set a ZStack with a background color on each newly created screen.
Is there a way to set a background color for the entire app globally?

you could try creating a View extension or a custom ViewModifier.
Or even better, a View extension with a specific style.

Is this a recommended approach?

"Recommended" for what, you didn't specify any criteria? Another option would be to create your own struct that will act as a template. For example, instead of a ZStack, you could have an AppStack (or whatever name you want) as your root wrapper. Whether or not I recommend this versus a view extension depends on your needs and how your app layout may evolve, which weren't provided.
